# changing url of iframe every 20 sec not working with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, browser, iframe, setinterval

I have an iframe that I wanna update every 20 seconds. So basically, the url of the iframe should change to a new one from the array and it refreshes, every 20 seconds but my code doesn't seem to work.

```
var Uni = {
    init: function () {
        this.refresh();
    },

    refresh: function () {
        var urlArr = [
            'http://www.smashingmagazine.com/learning-javascript-essentials-guidelines-tutorials/',
            'http://stephendnicholas.com/archives/310',
            'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptjunkie/ff696765', 
            'http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/jquery-each-examples/'
        ],

        iframeSrc = document.querySelector('#uni iframe').src;

        for (var i = 0, max = urlArr.length; i < max; i++) {
            setInterval(function(){
                iframeSrc = urlArr[i];
            }, 20000);
        }   
    }
}

Uni.init();
```

HTML:

```
<body id="uni">
   <iframe src="http://www.smashingmagazine.com/learning-javascript-essentials-guidelines-tutorials/">
   You browser doesn't support iframes, please update it.
   </iframe>
</body>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Check the last line of your `urlArr[]` declaration:</strike>

```
], // <- the comma should be a semicolon!
```

Thanks to @AndyE for the hint.

**Update:** Solution + [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vzwick/67DTf/2/)

```
var Uni = {
    interval_holder : false,
    urlArr : [],

    init: function (args) {
        if (args) {
            for (url in args) { this.addUrl(args[url]); }
        };
        this.refresh();
        this.interval_holder = setInterval('myuni.refresh()', 20000);
        return this;
    },

    refresh: function () {
        iframeObj = document.querySelector('#uni iframe');
        this.urlArr.unshift(iframeObj.src);
        iframeObj.src = this.urlArr.pop();
        return this;
    },

    stop : function () {
        clearInterval(this.interval_holder);
        return this;
    },

    addUrl : function(url) {
        this.urlArr.push(url);
        return this;
    },

    removeUrl : function(url) {
        this.urlArr.splice(this.urlArr.indexOf(url),1);
        return this;
    }
};

window.myuni = Uni.init([
    'http://www.smashingmagazine.com/learning-javascript-essentials-guidelines-tutorials/',
    'http://stephendnicholas.com/archives/310',
    'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptjunkie/ff696765', 
    'http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/jquery-each-examples/'
]);
```

Comment: Bonus: Added some handy `stop()`, `addUrl()` and `removeUrl()` functions.

Comment: Nope, that comma should definitely be a comma.  If it's not a comma then `iframeSrc` leaks into the global scope.

Comment: @AndyE Argh, you're absolutely right. Have a (meaningless, sadly) upvote!

Comment: @vzwick: thanks for your answer, but how can I do the following: when the user mouseover the document, the rotation of urls should stop and when the user mouseout or mousemove then the rotation of urls start again after 10sec?

Answer (score 2):

The iframe `src` attribute is only a string, not pointer. Changing it has no effect.

Have this instead:

```
iframeObj = document.querySelector('#uni iframe');
for (var i = 0, max = urlArr.length; i < max; i++) {
    setInterval(function(){
        iframeObj.src = urlArr[i];
    }, 20000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but your solution doesn't work, it says 'server cannot find file' and when I use console.log, it says undefined. Why?

Comment: You'd have problems with scoping in regard to `i`.